# Создание приложений на Android.

Tags: java, android, ide

Доброго времени суток. В общем, решил я создавать приложения на Android. В Google play я скачал AIDE - IDE на андройд. Он включает в себя C++ и java. С плюсами я знаком, то вот с явой даже на вы не разговариваю. Там был небольшой урок, написание приложения Hello world. Я написал его, а теперь не знаю куда двигаться дальше? Так вот вопрос: куда? Может кто подкинет уроков по яве? Может кто работал в данной IDE?

Comment: Вам придётся учить Java. Код C++ всё равно запускается в Далвике (это переделанная Java-машина для Android). То есть можно запустить приложение в Java и передать управление коду C++ только через JNI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите разрабатывать под Android на Android? 
Ставьте себе [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) или [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) и пишите нормально.
Неплохие [уроки](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html) по разработке. И [ещё](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/) с котятами ^_^